# jQuery : render only URL and <a> tag

Tags: jquery

I have asked this question already but didn't get correct answer so asking again.If i have a text like below in a textarea:

```
This is normal text this is www.google.com <a href='xyz.com'>this is link</a> 
<h3>don't render this h3 tag</h3> this is another <small>don't render 
this small tag</small> tag.<strong> don't render this strong tag</strong>
```

..and when i submit textarea and put the above string inside a div it should be render as:

**This is normal text this is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) [this is link](http://www.xyz.com)
`<h3>don't render this h3 tag</h3>` this is another `<small>don't render this small tag</small>` tag.`<strong> don't render this strong tag</strong>`**

i.e. **just want to render `<a>` tag and any url** (i.e. if i write www.google.com or http://www.google.com then it should show a link to google.com), **any other html tag should be as it is**. How can I do that?

The problem is if i d0n't do this then any user can play with `html` tag while posting any text in my website

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/PWhn3/

```
$(function(){
    $('a').replaceWith(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    });
});
```

**EDIT: (2/6/2014)**

You can apply the same logic regardless of tag type.

Either use:

```
    // by tag - I mean 'h1', 'h3', 'small'
    // so $('h1, h3, small')
    $(tag).replaceWith(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PWhn3/1/

or you can use [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$(function(){
    $('body :not(a, h3)').replaceWith(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PWhn3/2/

Comment: I said i don't want to parse all other tag except `url` and `a` . your solution is even parsing `h1` that actrually i dont want. It should be `<h1>` only even after parsing. if i will follow this solution the anybody can play with <html> tag while posting any reply or post

Comment: @Manish the example you provided asks to remove the `<a>`... `<a href=''>this is link</a>` to `this is link`. Also there is no mention of `<h1>`. Please edit your question and I will revise my solution.  Also please elaborate on what you mean by `url`...

Comment: I updated my question. please have a look. I just want to render any url or <a> tag available in the given text. All other text should be displayed as it is.